# Extrapolating sequence of numbers in R

Tags: r

I would like to increment numbers from the last observed number to the last number i.e. the NA values should be replaced with 35, 36, 38, 39

How can I go about it?

```
library(tidyverse)

trialdata <- tibble(
  id = c(13, 8, 20, 34, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Comment: what is the logic?

Comment: In what way is `34` the last observed number? Are you looking for "increment from the largest number so far"?

Comment: Check the last non missing number in this case 34, then create a sequence from 34+1 to nrow(data)

Comment: In your example, it is 4 though

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to arrange in ascending order

Comment: Can you guarantee all NAs are at the end? What if you had `id = c(NA,4,10, NA, NA, 20, NA)`. What should that look like?

Comment: In that case @MrFlick I would first sort in ascending order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to fill the NA id rows with a sequence that starts after the maximum non-NA value, then here's one way you could do it:

```
trialdata %>% 
  mutate(
    id_filled = cumsum(is.na(id)) + max(id, na.rm = T),
    id_filled = coalesce(id, id_filled)
  )

      id id_filled
   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1    13        13
 2     8         8
 3    20        20
 4    34        34
 5     4         4
 6    NA        35
 7    NA        36
 8    NA        37
 9    NA        38
10    NA        39
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option that could work on NAs that are between as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
trialdata %>% 
   mutate(id1 = id) %>% 
   fill(id1, .direction = "downup") %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(id1)) %>%
   mutate(id = id[!is.na(id)] + row_number() - row_number()[!is.na(id)]) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-id1, -grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 1
      id
   <dbl>
 1     4
 2     8
 3    13
 4    20
 5    34
 6    35
 7    36
 8    37
 9    38
10    39
```

On another data

```
trialdata1 <- structure(list(id = c(NA, 4, 10, NA, NA, 20, NA)), 
class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

the output is

```
# A tibble: 7 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     3
2     4
3    10
4    11
5    12
6    20
7    21
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative:

```
libaray(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

trialdata %>% 
  mutate(id1 = row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  fill(id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(row_number()>1, id+row_number()-1, id)) %>% 
  arrange(id1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id1)
```

```
     id
   <dbl>
 1    13
 2     8
 3    20
 4    34
 5     4
 6    35
 7    36
 8    37
 9    38
10    39
```

Answer (score 0):

For trailing `NA`s, you could do something like this.

```
x[is.na(x)] <- (x[sum(x > 0, na.rm=TRUE)]) + seq(sum(is.na(x)))
x
# [1]  4  8 13 20 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(sort(c(13, 8, 20, 34, 4)), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```